# Get app logs on crash

Tags: ionic-framework, crash, logcat, crash-reports

We have a situation here where we want to see some logging when our IONIC1 app crashes (even if it keeps crashing).
We thought about reading the logcat, but this only works if you have a rooted device.... It works then, but since we can't have all the devices here with us to manually run the adb script to grant root log to a logging app, I don't know what to do.
Anyone who had the same situation, and came with a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you should try some 3rd party logging tools, would recommend you start with Fabric! (Specifically for Crashlytics)

https://fabric.io/home

UPDATE:

If you want to write your logcats to a file, try something along these lines:

```
 try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d ");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            log.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    }
    String address = writeToLogcatFile(c, log.toString());
    boolean success = !address.equals("");
```

Also consider creating your own logger and just adding the ability to export it, just make a bunch of functions that calls your logging as appropriate

```
 public static void v(String TAG, String msg) {
    Logv(TAG, msg);
    if(showOnScreen) {
        Galgo.log(TAG + ": V: " + msg);
    }
}
 private static void Logv(String tag, String msg) {
    if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
        log.v(tag, msg);
    } else {
        logToTheFileToExportOrDBOrSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Comment: We actually just want the logcat from our application to be written to another file... We use Soti, so we can transfer the file from the device. Is there such a solution?

Comment: We rolled our own upload-logcat-thing with an AWS bucket, but I always hated it to be honest. You don't need to root the device to get your logcats.
You could also use the 3rd party tools' loggers to add information you're interested in and have it sent up as meta data with the crash. You always get a stacktrace, and then whatever other logging or meta data you've added. You could build this into your own logger. I haven't done this extra logging very much, we just use the stacktrace nowadays and some meta data, and then track Answers events (also fabric) for critical-non-fatal problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you give me some 3th party tools? How did you implement fabric in your own app? Do you get a crash report when the app crashes on startup? We got a black screen some days ago...

Comment: Fabric and Firebase are Google tools (for Android, iOS and Web), they're really really good! They're also very easy to set up! Just go to https://fabric.io/home sign up, and follow the steps, there's even a test button that forces a crash that will show up in your web console, their docs are always good and generally personalised for your project. I don't work for either, they've just saved me probably 1000s of hours of pain!